# Deleting Records Using a trigger once all records for an ID from the source table are deleted

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, database-trigger

I have two tables. As i cannot share the names of the table as it would be too specific i will just try to explain my query using generic tables.

The two tables are Score_table; which store students score and lets say the other table is a score dashboard (Student_Score_Table) which gives a view scores.

```
Score_table
|------------|------------|-------|
| Student ID | Subject ID | Score |  
|------------|------------|-------|
|     12     |      1     |   50  |
|------------|------------|-------|
|     12     |      2     |   70  |

Student_Score_Table
|--------------|------------|----------|
| Student Name | Subject A  | Subject B|  
|--------------|------------|----------|
|     Daniel   |      50    |    90    |
|--------------|------------|----------|
|     James    |      70    |   45     |
```

The students and subjects have their respective look up tables from where i get student name and subject.

There is a service which updates and deletes records in the `Score_table`

I have a problem here thinking of how to write a delete trigger.How can i write a trigger here which will:-
1. Delete the scores `Student_Score_Table` i.e. set it to null when i update the value in `Score_table`
2. Delete the entire record in `Student_Score_Table` when all the records for a particular student is deleted from `Score_table`

I have tried writing a Delete after trigger on `Score_table` and checking if there are any records for the student before deleting `Student_Score_Table` using a count query but with this i get result '1' instead of '0' count.

Comment: I'm making sure I understand the question correctly... Is THIS statement correct? :  "When the score_table is updated/deleted you want a trigger to remove any scores located in the Student_Score_Table tied to the student?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below the updated Trigger Code.  The updates I applied to the trigger as compared to my last Answer to this question do come with some warnings.  See [THIS SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707556/trigger-selection-from-same-table) to understand these concerns:

**Trigger Code**

```
create or replace TRIGGER student_score_trig
  AFTER
   DELETE OR UPDATE of score
  ON score_table
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  /* The below pragma allows us to SELECT from the same table that Triggered the Trigger.
   | Many circles say that doing any 'work' on the same table as the Trigger
   | is dangerous due to possible uncommited changes that are not able to be
   | seen by the code within the Trigger.
  */
  pragma autonomous_transaction;

  n_student_count  NUMBER  :=  0;

 BEGIN

  IF UPDATING THEN
    /* Not sure how you plan to tie the Subjects between each of the two tables
     | but I'm guessing this would be a non-issue for you.
    */
    UPDATE student_score_table SET subject_a = NULL
    WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
    ;
    COMMIT;
    dbms_output.put_line('This student_id was UPDATED: ' || :old.student_id || ' for subject_id: ' || :old.subject_id);
  END IF;


  IF DELETING THEN

    SELECT COUNT(student_id)
    INTO n_student_count
    FROM score_table
    WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line(n_student_count);

    IF n_student_count <= 1 THEN
      DELETE student_score_table
      WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
      ;
      COMMIT;
      dbms_output.put_line('This student_id was DELETED: ' || :old.student_id);
    END IF;

  END IF;

 exception
   when others then
     raise;
END;
```

> **Full Setup below**... creating tables... inserting data and compiling trigger is all below:

```
CREATE TABLE score_table 
( student_id  NUMBER,
  subject_id  NUMBER,
  score       NUMBER  
)
;
/

INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (12, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (12, 2, 70);
INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (10, 5, 60);

/

CREATE TABLE student_score_table 
( student_id    NUMBER,
  student_name  VARCHAR2(250),
  subject_a     NUMBER,
  subject_b     NUMBER
)
;

INSERT INTO student_score_table VALUES (12, 'Daniel', 50, 90);
INSERT INTO student_score_table VALUES (10, 'James', 70, 45);

/

--set define off; /* Depending on your interface this line might need to be removed */
--/

create or replace TRIGGER student_score_trig
  AFTER
   DELETE OR UPDATE of score
  ON score_table
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  /* The below pragma allows us to SELECT from the same table that Triggered the Trigger.
   | Many circles say that doing any 'work' on the same table as the Trigger
   | is dangerous due to possible uncommited changes that are not able to be
   | seen by the code within the Trigger.
  */
  pragma autonomous_transaction;

  n_student_count  NUMBER  :=  0;

 BEGIN

  IF UPDATING THEN
    /* Not sure how you plan to tie the Subjects between each of the two tables
     | but I'm guessing this would be a non-issue for you.
    */
    UPDATE student_score_table SET subject_a = NULL
    WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
    ;
    COMMIT;
    dbms_output.put_line('This student_id was UPDATED: ' || :old.student_id || ' for subject_id: ' || :old.subject_id);
  END IF;


  IF DELETING THEN

    SELECT COUNT(student_id)
    INTO n_student_count
    FROM score_table
    WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line(n_student_count);

    IF n_student_count <= 1 THEN
      DELETE student_score_table
      WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
      ;
      COMMIT;
      dbms_output.put_line('This student_id was DELETED: ' || :old.student_id);
    END IF;

  END IF;

 exception
   when others then
     raise;
END;
```

> See it in Action

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what i was looking for. The pragma autonomous_transaction did the trick. I had the insert and update taken care of. Only the delete was not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using separate table and triggers I would use simple pivot query:

```
select *
  from (
    select subject_name, student_name, score
      from score 
      join students using (student_id)
      join subjects using (subject_id))
  pivot (max(score) for subject_name in ('Subject A', 'Subject B'))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a16e40d2601f53f919a3e9d80153dbc2)</sup>**

Make a view, use it instead of table `student_subject_score` and forget about triggers and problems related to synchronisation.

Your current solution makes things complicated. You could do trigger on `score` but checking if any rows exists for specific student requires `select` also on table score. And this is not allowed on row-level triggers, causes `mutating table` errors. To solve this you would need probably compound trigger. Also your design requires either complicated `case when` (because we have to find which column to nullify), either dynamic SQL. What for, when old, simple and reliable `view` solves all problems?

Comment: This is something that i thought about. May be in terms of the design this would be the best solution. However the student/score sheet problem is just an example(close to the actual problem i am trying to solve). The problem i have includes more columns which would mean i would have to write more than one pivot statement. Also i would need to filter on certain columns as part of certain requirement of my application. I know this is very doable and i'm just being lazy but i came here wondering i could write a trigger for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

While not being 100% sure what you are needing I was able to accomplish what I believe you are seeking to accomplish using this Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_score_trig
  AFTER
   DELETE OR UPDATE of score
  ON score_table
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN

  DELETE student_score_table
  WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
  ;

 exception
   when others then
     raise;
END;
```

> Full Setup below... creating tables... inserting data and compiling trigger is all below:

```
CREATE TABLE score_table 
( student_id  NUMBER,
  subject_id  NUMBER,
  score       NUMBER  
)
;
/

INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (12, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (12, 2, 70);
INSERT INTO score_table VALUES (10, 5, 60);

/

CREATE TABLE student_score_table 
( student_id    NUMBER,
  student_name  VARCHAR2(250),
  subject_a     NUMBER,
  subject_b     NUMBER
)
;

INSERT INTO student_score_table VALUES (12, 'Daniel', 50, 90);
INSERT INTO student_score_table VALUES (10, 'James', 70, 45);

/

set define off; /* Depending on your interface this line might need to be removed */

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_score_trig
  AFTER
   DELETE OR UPDATE of score
  ON score_table
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN

  DELETE student_score_table
  WHERE student_id = :old.student_id
  ;

 exception
   when others then
     raise;
END;
```

> See it in Action

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution you have provided. Maybe I have not framed the question correctly or just used a bad example here. Let me try to explain. I will not be deleting all the scores of a student. May be I only delete of subject A and not subject B. In that case in the student score table I need to just update subject A  score to null. Also I need to handle case where I have to delete entire record as u have shown. And this is when there are no more records for a student in the the score_table. I need to handle both these conditions in the same delete and update trigger.

Comment: IF DELETING THEN 
  Dostuff
END IF;

IF INSERTING THEN 
  Do stuff
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN
END IF;

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer but look at my comment.  Basically you can write code based on what action occured.  I can possibly add to my answer tomorrow if my workload allows for it.

Comment: Yes I have tried to use IF DELETING but I am not sure how to handle both the cases that i have mentioned