# Date time format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am new to sql and am working on an example. Among the tables I have created, I have the comments table:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
club       VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
nick         VARCHAR2(35),
msg_date   DATE,
title        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
director   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
subject    VARCHAR2(100),
message    VARCHAR2(1500),
valoration NUMBER(2),
CONSTRAINT PK_COMMENTS PRIMARY KEY (nick,msg_date),
CONSTRAINT FK_COMMENTS_MEMBER FOREIGN KEY (nick,club) REFERENCES membership ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_COMMENTS_MOVIES  FOREIGN KEY (title,director) REFERENCES movies,
CONSTRAINT CK_COMMENTS_VAL CHECK (valoration<11) 
);
```

I am asked to create a trigger that does the following:
if a comment arrives on the same date as another one already stored, register it with the date
'one second later'. 
The problem I have is that I do not know how to convert the 'one second' later into a date. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

msg_date + interval '1' second

or alternatively msg_date + (1/(24*60*60))

However this whole scenario is fraught with danger. While checking existing messages in the table within the trigger the table may be changing in other transactions and so there is a real risk of race conditions here - two messages both adding 1 second to an existing message will then have the same date. This would be the case whether the check was in a trigger or application code.

If this is a real world scenario I would avoid the trigger, use a timestamp rather than date, where the precision is between millis and nanos and consider how to deal with the lower risk of messages with the same timestamp as a business problem - what is the implication if it does occur.

Comment: The problem is that the DATE format is 'DD/MM/YYYY'

Comment: As a varchar2? You can convert to date but if you only have the date to the nearest day then adding 1 second is pretty meaningless I'd have thought?

Comment: But I can see in the table definition it is a date, and date type is stored to the nearest second.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413

Comment: So if you are inserting a value that is just at the precision of day, then you are effectively storing that date at midnight. Adding 1 second is no problem, you just have the same date 1 second after midnight which makes sense if the aim is to force date ordering when messages are created at only day accuracy

Comment: is there any way to add 'one second later' to the column? I mean converting 'one second later', which is a varchar, to a date format

Comment: 'one second later' is not much different to +interval '1' second but the latter is valid syntax. You would have to manually interpret and convert the text 'one second later' into a valid format, which you could do with text manipulation and mapping eg one -> 1 but not sure why you would need to do that. Maybe expand on you specific requirement if Oracle built in features don't do what you need.

Comment: I mean specifically why the need to handle the string 'one second later' if you are the one creating a trigger

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8707556/2568649, you may need to find max(msg_date) + interval '1' second where trunc(msg_date) = trunc(new:msg_date)

Comment: Thanks for the help btw

Comment: No probs - hope it got you a bit further - hope you have lots of SQL fun :-)